# SQL query with meta_key,meta_value and have 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do an SQL query to find a form id of the Registration form of the user on a wordpress site, because this form doesn't have the id of the user yet, I have to find the user email which is unique and check if the gdprchekbox-1 is true because it is only used for the registering form so if I have both conditions I know that the form ID will be the registering form of the user.

So if both conditions are met I should only have one result of the entry_id form.

I have tried :

```
SELECT entry_id 
FROM `mod114_frmt_form_entry_meta` 
WHERE (`meta_key`, `meta_value`) IN (("email-1","emailofuser@mail.com"),("gdprcheckbox-1","true"));
```

Which was the closest I got but the IN clause makes it so it says OR and I would need both conditions to work.

```
SELECT entry_id 
FROM `mod114_frmt_form_entry_meta` 
where meta_key IN("email-1","gdprcheckbox-1") 
  AND meta_value IN("emailofuser@mail.com","true") LIMIT 1;
```

This one was close as well but it still doesn't work well.

My table is as follows :

| meta_id | entry_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - 1297 | 72 | email-1 | emailofuser@mail.com |
| - 1316 | 72 | gdprcheckbox-1 | true |

I hope I was clear enough, thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to find 1 record, and only when `gdprcheckbox-1` is true:

```
SELECT entry_id 
FROM `mod114_frmt_form_entry_meta` 
WHERE (`meta_key`, `meta_value`) = ("email-1","emailofuser@mail.com")
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM `mod114_frmt_form_entry_meta` 
              WHERE (`meta_key`, `meta_value`) = ("gdprcheckbox-1","true")
             )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, this query seems more fitting than what I tried previously,  I tried it but I got the error : #1064 - Syntax error near 'LIMIT 0, 30' on line 6.

I am not too sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: I do not see `LIMIT 0,30` in this SQL statement.

Comment: Please see the screenshot of the error, I find it strange too : [Here](https://ibb.co/rm0LDjZ).

Comment: Sorry, I had some misplaced`( )` .....